# Carousel not working on jQuery Galleria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, galleria

I am using the Galleria jQuery slideshow and I'm having an issue with the carousel of thumbnails on the bottom. I know that within the code, if a 'carousel' is present (too many thumbnails to display on the main page) the thumbnails-container div has a class of .carousel added to it. This is not happening on mine, it's just showing overflowed thumbnails. Also the right and left nav items have the .disabled class added to them on load.

Is there a known issue of why this would happen? I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. The only error I get in the console on load is "Uncaught Error: Fatal error: Could not extract a stage height from the CSS. Traced height: 0px." but I don't believe this is related (it could be though). The slideshow loads alright with this error and everything works except for the carousel. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you show some code or setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yeah I'll set one up now.

Comment: Well it seems to work on JSFiddle, now I'm even more confused...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FGbN7/3/

Answer (score 0):

You probably have set option carousel:false somewhere.
`(http://jsfiddle.net/FGbN7/4/)`